# Как сделать взаимодействие с рекламой гугл на сайте

Tags: javascript, python, django, steam

Я хочу сделать сайт на Django который за нажатие по рекламному баннеру будет выводить стим ключ на экран.Как так сделать?

Comment: Во народ пошел, сайта еще в помине нет, а уже лишь бы побольше рекламы, такой проект по умолчанию провален, не те цели вы преследуете

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, вешаете обработчик на JS на body, отслеживая все iframe гугла, при событии показываете модалку с ключом

```
$('body').click('iframe', function(e) {
    ... // Открываем модалку с ключом
});
```